# iOS Static TableView Selection identify

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a static tableview inside a container, inside a view. There are 5 cells, each representing a different service. The service detail view is generic to all 5, so will be used for each.

I'm stuck as to how to differentiate the selection of a specific cell as so far i've only instantiated table views via code (using array, UITableViewDataSourceDelegate etc).

Each cell is visually identified using a Label.

Is there a way to assign each cell something like a storyboard id? or even an overkill way of determining the cell label's value for comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy if you have static 5 cells only in table view.

Just need to identify the cell by using `NSIndexPath`.

```
UITableViewCell *cell1 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
UITableViewCell *cell2 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
UITableViewCell *cell3 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]];
UITableViewCell *cell4 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0]];
UITableViewCell *cell5 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0]];
```

Assign a tag in `cellForAtIndexPath` method

```
label.tag = indexPath.row;
```

And using above cell object get respected label.

```
UILabel *label1 = (UITextField *)[cell1 viewWithTag:0];
UILabel *label2 = (UITextField *)[cell2 viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *label3 = (UITextField *)[cell3 viewWithTag:2];
UILabel *label4 = (UITextField *)[cell4 viewWithTag:3];
UILabel *label5 = (UITextField *)[cell5 viewWithTag:4];
```

Comment: I had a couple additional issues with setting the right delegate (thought I could get away with using the single view controller as delegate for both viewcontroller & contained table view), however my overall solution for the question was too switch on indexPath.row, similar to your answer, 0 => cell1, 1 => cell2 etc.